# How to check only specified checkboxes with jquery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes. I want to check and uncheck some of them or all when I click on appropriate button.

For example when I click over "Check All" button I want to be checked all buttons. When I click over "Male" button I want to be checked only checkboxes where "class" is equal to "male". When I click over "Female" button I want to be checked only checkboxes where class is equal to "female". When I click over "None" button I want to be checked only checkboxes where class is equal to "none". How can I do that with jquery?

```
<br>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_all"> Check all
<input type="checkbox" class="check_all_females"> Females
<input type="checkbox" class="check_all_males"> Males
<input type="checkbox" class="check_all_none"> None
</div>


<input type="checkbox" class='male'> John<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='male'> Maria<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='male'> Ali<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='male'> Tural<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='female'> John<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='female'> Fuass<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='female'> Jadsa<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='none'> Dasda<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='none'> Wers<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='none'> Saqa<BR>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this:

```
$(function(){


 $("div.mains input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var rel = $(this).attr("rel"),
        checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    switch(rel)
    {
        case "all":
            if(!checked)
            {
                $(".sub input:checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
            }
            else
            {
                $(".sub input:checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");
            }
        break;
        default:
            if(!checked)
            {
                $(".sub input." + rel).removeAttr( "checked");
            }
            else
            {
                $(".sub input." + rel).attr( "checked", "checked");
            }

    }
});

});
```

HTML

```
<br>
<div class="mains">
<input type="checkbox" rel="all" class="check_all"> Check all
<input type="checkbox" rel="female" class="check_all_females"> Females
<input type="checkbox" rel="male" class="check_all_females"> Males
<input type="checkbox" rel="none" class="check_all_females"> None
</div>

<div class="sub">
<input type="checkbox" class='male'> John<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='male'> Maria<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='male'> Ali<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='male'> Tural<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='female'> John<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='female'> Fuass<BR>
<input type="checkbox" class='female'> Jadsa<BR>
</div>
```

Try out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2R2CC/

Comment: Updated my code, but it was already working, added some extra feature to uncheck all of the type.

Comment: Do this `$(".sub input:checkbox").removeAttr("checked");` before the `if(!checked)` after `default:`

Comment: You can vote up this answer or press the donate button on [this url](http://lutrasoft.nl/jQuery/fancyform/).

Comment: So sorry for disturbing you again. But I now  I can't choose more than one checkbox. For example I want to choose both male and female, and uncheck others.

Comment: I do my best to appreciate your work. 
It did not work properly. Sorry again. It's so important for me. Previous version was better. I will use that. How can i get previous version?

Comment: Just go to: http://jsfiddle.net/2R2CC/1/ to have a previouw working version. This is starting to look as a chat, be more specific otherwise this will never work.

Comment: I checked this version http://jsfiddle.net/2R2CC/3/  It works great. But I want that to work as before. That is to check only one checkbox. That is forexample only male.